# How to get Firestore Index Merge to work?

Tags: firebase, indexing, google-cloud-firestore

I am having trouble using firestore index merging in order to reduce the number of required indices.

Consider this example situation:

Firestore Collection: test/somedoc

```
{
  a: '1',
  b: '1',
  c: '1',
  d: '1'
}
```

This will cause Firestore to create 4 automatic single field indices on test for fields a to d.

Querying this table with a few equality conditions and one unrelated sort:

```
    await db.collection('test')
        .where('a', '==', '1')
        .where('b', '==', '1')
        .where('c', '==', '1')
        .orderBy('d')
        .get();
```

This causes Firebase to fail with a prompt for a composite index creation with all fields included. This is expected.

Now according to the docs (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview#taking_advantage_of_index_merging), if you already have a composite on e.g. fields c and d, firestore will use index merging instead of requiring a composite index on all fields.

[image: firestore-index]

However if you create an index on collection test e.g. with c asc, d asc, the query will still fail with prompting to create the full composite index.

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: FirebaseError: The query requires an index.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6):

@Aurangzeb has the correct answer but I want to elaborate

So it is true that if you want to use index merging on that query you need 3 composite indexes `(a, d)`, `(b, d)`, and `(c, d)`.

However using a single `(a, b, c, d)` index will still be faster in some cases and you should consider adding it anyway. Index merging is slower in the case where the result sets from the 3 indexes are of very different sizes. Consider your query:

```
collection
  .where(a == 1)
  .where(b == 1)
  .where(c == 1)
  .orderBy(d)
```

Let's say you have a collection of a million documents and 50% of them have `a == 1` or `b == 1` but only 0.1% of them have `c == 1`. In this case reading from the `(a, d)` index is actually doing quite a bit of wasted work before the `(c, d)` index eliminates most of the results. A single `(a, b, c, d)` index does the least work possible. This is why the Firebase SDKs and console always suggest the most exact index even if there is a way to satisfy the query with merged indexes.

Comment: Hi, reading the docs here: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/optimize-indexes#:~:text=S%20is%20the%20size%20of%20the%20smallest%20set%20of%20potential%20entities%20from%20a%20single%20index%20scan.
it says the performance is based on "the smallest set of potential entities from a single index scan".
Shouldn't this mean that in your example, the smallest set is the set where c==1 which is only 0.1%, so performance is still good?
My understanding was that performance was bad if EACH individual criteria had a high number of matches, while the result set was small.

Answer (score 5):

Ok finally understood the problem here.

In order to index merge to work, you need **composite-indices** that cover all related fields. The auto-generated single field indices won't be used for merging.

Consequently, if you create two additional composite indices

- a asc, d asc
- b asc, d asc

then all fields will be covered and index merge will be used automatically.

Comment: This is the correct answer, thank you for posting it!